# Close and flag modal window

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

Using a computer with a lower resolution when clicking the *close* or *flag* link on a question, that has a small description, the modal popup window has a lower z-index than the top menu bar, which makes it not possible to close it using the upper right X

Screen dump

[image]

Comment: Escape, or click anywhere outside the dialog will close it.

Comment: @Oded Yes, noticed that, still, looks somewhat not good so thought I drop a note

Comment: FYI: it should be fixed now.

Comment: @Paweł If you scroll down on a question which have larger content, you'll see it is still there, less then it was though

Comment: @Oded If you scroll down on a question which have larger content, you'll see it is still there, less then it was though